# Raspberry Pi Zero As A Mountable USB Stick?

Tags: usb, mount

Is it possible to format a Raspberry Pi Zero to automatically mount as a hard drive when plugged into a computer via USB? If so, are there any available tutorials or resources to help me achieve this?

Comment: Stephan, welcome to the RPi flavored corner of Stack Exchange. As is, your question is way too broad to be reasonably answered in this format. I suggest you take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and take a look at [what kind of questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) work well here.

Comment: Your project has a ton of moving parts. If you need help from us, you'll need to break it down into much, much smaller and more manageable pieces. Presenting as a mountable device, being powered by a battery, and interfacing with Dropbox are all completely separate projects and can be rather involved in their own right.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll try moving forward with just one part at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [this](http://pi.gbaman.info/?p=699) to create a 1.5 MB Pi USB memory stick:

**g_mass_storage** - To have your Pi Zero appear as a mass storage device (flash drive), first create a mini filesystem in a file on your Pi with:

```
    dd if=/dev/zero of=./piusb.bin bs=512 count=2880
```

and set it up as a fat32 filesystem with

```
    mkdosfs ./piusb.bin
```

Then load the drive use:

```
    sudo modprobe g_mass_storage file=./piusb.bin stall=0
```

Of course you can make the `piusb.bin` file as large as you want your USB file system to be.  512 bytes * 2880 = 1.5 MB

Thanks to [this Raspberry Pi forum posting](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=154384) I found that if you use `g_multi` instead of `g_mass_storage` (or in fact `g_serial` and `g_ether`) you can use all of the USB gadgets!!!

Therefore you want the following in your `/etc/rc.local`:

```
    /bin/sleep 5
    /sbin/modprobe g_multi file=/home/pi/piusb.bin
```

As an added plus you can now also use `screen` to get to the console of your Pi using the command:

```
    screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200
```

You may need to enable serial console using the command:

```
    sudo systemctl enable getty@ttyGS0.service
```